# How to add AutoFilter to Excel Cell with jxl java jar

Tags: java, excel, api, jxl, autofilter

Does anyone know how to add **autofilter** to a **cell** in excel using **jxl**? I can't quite figure it out.
Any and all help with be appreciated.. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with **jxl**, you must use **Apache POI** http://poi.apache.org/
(or something else if there is anything else)

Apache POI has more functions and I find it more programer friendly.

Great examples for Apache POI are here
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html
http://www.kodejava.org/browse/49.html

Comment: It seems [it's possible](http://www.docjar.org/docs/api/jxl/biff/AutoFilter.html), still can't figure out how